# What is this in JS flie

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file in which it has the code given below. Can any body tell me what is this I thinks it is a URL , I have this code in a JS mcpe mod this code give a image

```
var buttonNotPressed = "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";
```

Comment: This is some sort of encoding.  Can you tell us more about the js file that contains this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded PNG image. This image, to be exact:

[image]

I had a hunch it would be an image (encoding images as Base64 is pretty common) and used [this website](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) to decode the string.

**Edit:** Thank you Lee, for adding the link to the Base64 wiki page. I'd also recommend reading up on the [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and "[When to base64 encode images (and when not to)](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/)" by David Calhoun. It's pretty dated and I haven't read it in a while, but most of it should still apply.

Comment: thank you very much and can you please tell how to encode them also

Comment: There are a lot of online "image to Base64" converters you can use. You'll also need to read up on the data URI scheme and best practices. Encoding images is something you should only do if necessary.